# Why is $\frac{x^2+x-30}{x-5}=x+6$ incorrect, and $\lim_{x\to5}\frac{x^2+x-30}{x-5}=\lim_{x\to 5}(x+6)$ correct?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

For part 1, option two is incorrect and for part two, option 3 is incorrect. I figured that for part 1, option three is correct and part two its either option 1 or two.

[image]

Comment: The only correct answers are the ones you have chosen.  Option 1 in part b is incorrect.  $x$ and $x+1$ are both continuous, but din't have the same limit at any point.

Comment: In a), I disagree with the terminology of the question. As an *identity*, the expression is false as it does not hold for all $x$. As an *equation*, there is no problem: the solution set is $\mathbb R\setminus\{5\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Your two answers are correct, as [saulspatz](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/235128/saulspatz)'s question [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3641153/what-is-wrong-with-the-equation/3641163#comment7482520_3641153) also states. Also, part $1$'s option $2$ is incorrect (since the LHS is defined at $x = 0$), and part $2$'s option $3$ is also incorrect (since the equation in part (a) is incorrect, both because it states so and, more importantly, because its third option, which you've chosen, explains that the LHS expression is not defined for $x = 5$).

For part $2$, note option $1$ is incorrect since $\frac{x^2 + x - 30}{x-5}$ is *not* continuous at $x = 5$ (although it's continuous at all points), although $x + 6$ is continuous at all points $x \in \mathbb{R}$.